# Checking installed application in a multilingual scenario

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0

On startup of my WPF application , I am also starting the process of iTunes.exe.
For this I haved checked using code that if application Itunes is already installed start it on application startup.

It is working fine when I am using Windows with English culture.

When I am installing the same setup on a japanese machine, (where i have already installed Itunes), the process(iTunes.exe) is not started on the application startup.
Is this due the culture difference?

```
public bool IsApplictionInstalled(string display_name)
    {
        RegistryKey key;

        // search in: CurrentUser
        key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall");
        bool appInstalledUnderCurrentUser = SearchInstalledApplication(key, display_name);

        // search in: LocalMachine_32
        key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall");
        bool appInstalledUnderLocalMachine32 = SearchInstalledApplication(key, display_name);

        // search in: LocalMachine_64
        key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall");
        bool appInstalledUnderLocalMachine64 = SearchInstalledApplication(key, display_name);


        if (appInstalledUnderCurrentUser || appInstalledUnderLocalMachine32 || appInstalledUnderLocalMachine64)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }


private bool SearchInstalledApplication(RegistryKey key, string display_name)
    {
        string displayName;
        if (key != null)
        {
            foreach (String keyName in key.GetSubKeyNames())
            {
                RegistryKey subkey = key.OpenSubKey(keyName);
                displayName = subkey.GetValue("DisplayName") as string;
                if (display_name.Equals(displayName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == true)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I have checked on the Japanese machine too that the application exists in the registry with the same Display name "iTunes". Why is it happening so?? Unable to make out.